# SQL - Check For Duplicate Values

Tags: javascript, sql, appcelerator

(This project is all written in JS)

So, I have a table called `paid_offers`, and two columns called `offer_id` and `entity_id`
What I'm trying to do is get a count of all the `offer_id` values associated with a single `entity_id`.

**EDIT:** Example: entity_id A has 35 offers available (so, there are 35 rows with unique offer_ids, but all the same entity_id)

So, getting the count is no problem with `arrayList.length`, but I just need an approach to getting the actual array. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: As per request, more information! I'm going to be using the output as an array.

So, this project is written using Titanium (From appcelerator). I don't need anything besides the query. So, It'd be what's inside the quotes here, for those who don't know.

`var offersList = db.execute("SELECT entity_id FROM paid_offers");`

Now, the goal is not to just get the list of ID's but instead the list of `offer_id` values associated with each unique `entity_id` value. I would think it would look close to:

`var offersList = db.execute("SELECT offer_id FROM paid_offers WHERE entity_id = entity_id`

Except that wouldn't work, but that's my train of thought while looking through this.

Comment: You need to give more details to get a helpful answer.

Comment: It's plenty simple. The last question I did, everyone disliked too many details. I shortened this to necessary information. Please, do tell, what more information would you need? I'd be happy to provide them for you!

Comment: You to get the count of what? How the array you're getting looks like? how do you get it? ... so on.

Comment: Don't let it bother you some people just down vote on questions they think are too novice or easy . They often forget they were a novice at some point too . I up voted this to keep you at 0

Comment: Not sure about your previous question but there really isn't enough detail here... You need to give a little more detail - how exactly are you querying your (MySQL, MSSQL, ???) database from Javascript  -using a library? What form is the data you're being given in? An object, an array, ????

Comment: @BobSinclar, it's a guess but there was probably a down-vote because someone _believed_ as per the tool-tip "The question does not show any research effort". Jake, it's often helpful to post [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). This shows the community at large that you're not just expecting them do do you coding for them. It also helps _you_ by helping everyone else  see what you're trying to do, which is the best possible explanation of your problem. It may improve the quality of answers you receive as well.

Comment: Downvotes can usually be reversed by editing the question to be better (so either the original voter or another will vote it as "useful").

Comment: I'm going to add more to the question, as per avoiding any more problems. Wasn't trying to head that direction, but I'll go ahead and try to fix it.

Comment: So are you trying to get a "count of all the `offer_id` values associated with a single `entity_id`" (Entity 1 has 2 offers; Entity 2 has 34 offers...) or "the list of `offer_id` values associated with each unique `entity_id` value" (Entity 1 has offers A and B; Entity 2 has offers A, C, D...)?

Comment: I'm so glad you asked, but it's be your first option you have there. You said it exactly. I assume that in order to get that first option, you'd have to go through the second one and return the count of offers A,B,C... probably. But yes, I'm just trying for the count, and I'll be getting the actual list much later on

Comment: Example: entity_id A has 35 offers available (so, there are 35 rows with unique offer_ids, but all the same entity_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to count the offers for each entity, it's

```
SELECT entity_id, COUNT(offer_id) As Count
FROM   paid_offers
GROUP BY entity_id
```

This will only find entities with at least one offer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had exactly this code at one point, and here I made the mistake of reversing entity_id and offer_id in each case rendering it useless. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're after is this...

```
SELECT offer_id, COUNT(*) As Count
FROM   paid_offers
GROUP BY offer_id
```

Which would give something like.

```
offer_id   Count
1          1
2          4
3          2
...
```

Note that it will exclude any offer_id that isn't present in the table so there will never be a count of 0

One other note on using the Array.length() to do a count - it returns a (potentially large) recordset to JS which then counts it. This uses a lot of resources for not a lot of benefit - better to do the `COUNT` in SQL (as shown above) and just get the result.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be coming out as just 1 each time. Here is how I'm calling it: `offersList[i].Count.toString() + ' Offer(s) Availible'` And then it just returns '1' each time. 

Just to make sure I said it as well as I should have before, I'm trying to get the count of the unique `offer_id` rows with the same `entity_id` value. That way I can say 'Walmart (entity_id of 5) has 5 offers availible (offer_ids of 1,2,3,etc)

Comment: Try running the SQL directly, you _should_ be getting the table as described in the answer, in which case, each value of `i` should represent a different row (not necessarily the matching `offer_id` as we aren't specifically ordering). Try using a debugger and examining the `offersList` variable (eg in Firebug) and see what you actually get. Better yet, run the Query against SQL directly - then we'll know if it's a query problem or a JS problem. I'll have another look at this in a few hours

Comment: Got it to work, just had to reverse the code you had and replace 'offer_id' in your code with 'entity_id' and vice versa

Comment: @Jakexx360 Yeah, I spotted the accepted answer - that'll teach me not to copy and paste from the Q :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't simple or possible with pure SQL since each column in the result can always only be a single value but you need a list. Try this approach instead:

```
select entity_id, offer_id
from paid_offers
```

In JavaScript, read the results and create an array for each `entity_id` and append the `offer_id`s to that array. After processing all the results of the query, you will have the structure that you want. Pseudocode:

```
data = {}
for (entity_id, offer_id in rows) {
    var a = data[entity_id]
    if (a === undefined) {
        a = []
        data[entity_id] = a
    }

    a.push(offer_id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So how about getting the other column in an array list . Then have an outlet for loop that goes through each offer_id . Then on the inside go through each Entity_id . If more then one entity Id shows up don't delete that offer_id from your final array list .

Or why not just do it with SQL calls ?